# Seleccionar texto no formateado en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día gente!
Soy nuevo por acá y practicando para un proyecto personal me encontre en la siguiente situación:

Desde un archivo HTML, tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
<div class="Contenido">
      <h1> Juan Jose Fierro </h1>
      <h2 id="subtitulo"> herreria industrial</h2>
        Mar del Plata <br/>
      <strong>Carasa 1723</strong><br/>
</div>
```

Al momento de seleccionar los distintos tags, desde javascript, me encuentro en el siguiente dilema:

si quiero seleccionar el texto dentro encabezado  puedo hacer

```
document.querySelector('h1').innerText
```

lo mismo tambien podría hacer en el encabezado 2 incluso usando:

```
document.getElementById('subtitulo').innerText
```

Pero, acá me viene la duda ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar solo el "Mar del Plata"? Porque si le pido el innerText al div completo me trae todo.

Comment: Hola Torrente, poder se puede, el tema es ¿la estructura es fija, no cambia? De eso va a depender la solución

Comment: Si. la estructura es fija.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Opción 1: apuntar al hijo

Una opción es "apuntar" específicamente al elemento teniendo en cuenta que es el hijo número 4 del `div.Contenido`.
Usando [`childnodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) podes seleccionarlo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let text = document.querySelector('.Contenido').childNodes[4].textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="Contenido">
  <h1> Juan Jose Fierro </h1>
  <h2 id="subtitulo"> herreria industrial</h2>
  Mar del Plata <br/>
  <strong>Carasa 1723</strong><br/>
</div>
```

---

### Opción 2: buscar el hermano

Otra opción es buscar el hermano siguiente del `h2`.
Usando [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) podes encontrarlo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let text = document.querySelector('h2').nextSibling.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="Contenido">
  <h1> Juan Jose Fierro </h1>
  <h2 id="subtitulo"> herreria industrial</h2>
  Mar del Plata <br/>
  <strong>Carasa 1723</strong><br/>
</div>
```

***Nota**: También se puede lograr usando [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) desde el `strong`.*

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, realmente soluciona mi inconveniente.